# how to get lastRowNum() from a specific file from a list of file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am unable to get the lastRowNum() for a specific file while reading it from a folder.
The lastRowNum() method returns, last row after consolidating all the files in folder. I need a specific file .

Below is the code used

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles)
{
if (file.isFile()&&(file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.')+1).equals("xlsx")))
{
 Workbook workbook =WorkbookFactory.create(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                       Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                       int j = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                       System.out.println(j);
    }   
}
```

I am getting output as 340 which is the sum of all values in all files in the folder.
But for 1st sheet it should be 40. As in 1st sheet it contains 40 rows only

Comment: You are getting 340 for the first sheet of the first Document or the first sheet of the Last Document? Or is it an incremental series with 340 printed in the end?

Comment: Its the incremental series with 340 printed. Its taking all the files in the folder, and taking the 1st sheet of the file of all the files & giving the sum of all the lines as 340.

Answer (score 0):

I used a break statement, in the loop, when the rowIterator.next() method returns null.This way one sheet is over and I again start over other sheet.
I am not calculating the lastRowNum() value to iterate through the rows.
This somehow, allowed me to read all the files.

```
Workbook workbook =WorkbookFactory.create(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                       Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("XYZ");
                       Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                       rowIterator.next(); //Skipping headings              
                       while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                       {
                           Row row = rowIterator.next();
                           Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                           SheetObject obj1= new SheetObject();

                           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                           if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                               break;
                           }
                           obj1.setValue1(val);
                           String temp = cell.getStringCellValue();
                           obj1.setModule(temp);  }
```

But still , the solution of the question is pending.